# CSS not applied to content loaded via AJAX in IE7

Tags: css, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a problem with IE7 specifically.  I have a tabbed content area and each tab's content is being loaded via AJAX.  This works fine in FF and Chrome but IE7 renders the AJAX loaded content incorrectly. Its as though some of the CSS styles aren't being applied only after the AJAX call.

The JS:

```
// Set up the AJAX object parameters
var tabOptions = {
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: '/wp-content/themes/iview/ajax/latest-posts.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, XMLHttpRequest) {
        $('<p>Sorry, your request could not be completed at the moment due to ' + errorThrown + ' </p>')
            .appendTo('#tabbed-content')
    },
    success: function(html, textStatus) {
        $('#tabbed-content').find('#loader')
                            .remove()
                            .end()
                            .find('.jspPane')
                            .append(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which styles don't seem to be applied? Perhaps those particular styles are not very compatible with IE7?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two elements with the same id. Make sure that the content of #tabbed-content doesn't have an element with an already used id.

Comment: Turns out I needed to load the latest HTML5 shiv for IE8 and below (currently using modernizr)

Thanks for your help